# Wordpress - Handle GET request

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to be able to catch GET (or POST) requests within a plugin and I can't find the right way to do so.

What is the correct way to build the request and what hook should I use in order to be able to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );  ?>

<h1>Currently Browsing Page <?php echo (int) $paged; ?></h1>
```

Example 2:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "my_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

you can check the details instruction here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. for me seemed $_POST are not displayed because in new php they are deprecated. 
Solution is init hook.

```
function catch_post(){
var_dump($_REQUEST);
}
add_action ( 'init', 'catch_post');
```

U can set form action as - `get_home_url()`